# Run Selective Test Classes in VSTS

Tags: c#, filter, continuous-integration, automated-tests, azure-pipelines-build-task

In Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) when defining a build I can filter specific tests to be included or excluded when running tests.

**Question**: How do I filter complete test classes from execution? The example in the screenshot demonstrates how I filter tests based on their category.

**Sample** test class which I'd like to exclude:

```
[TestClass] // .NET 4.5
public class SampleTests
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Integration")]
    public void Test1() {}

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Integration")]
    public void Test2() {}

    ...
}
```

**Current configuration** to exclude my integration tests:

[image: test category filtering]

**Trial**: The filter criteria `ClassName!=SampleTests` doesn't work. It seems to be reserved for store apps only. Fairly good documentation here: [MSDN Blog by Vikram Agrawal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikramagrawal/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter/).

**Reason for asking**: I've got test classes initialize lots of data first before running any test and run a clean-up job at the end. When all my tests are excluded via the aforesaid filter the class initialization and clean-up still happen which consumes a lot of time and resources. I like to optimize this.

Comment: This is a great question. Who develops "store apps" anyways, and why does that have anything to do with TFS testing :( very strange. Anyways did you ever find a solution or workaround to this issue? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: Hi @DavidRogers, still having this issue to solve. Peter's solution wasn't bringing me any further yet unfortunately. Currently I am just tolerating the long test runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
FullyQualifiedName!=namespace.SampleTests
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter! The ~ operator is for inclusions, but I need a solution for exclusions. How would you use the ~ operator to exclude a class/namespace? Or are you suggesting `FullyQualifiedName!=SampleTests`?

Comment: Then you probably can use FullyQualifiedName!=namespace.SampleTests

Comment: Ran multiple trials including a fully qualified namespace and class name as defined in the assembly without success.

Comment: I suspect that the FQN contains the assembly name as well, have you tried `!(FullyQualifiedName~NameSpace.Class)`? It tends to be easier to do this at the assembly name level and add `;-:SampleTestsAssembly.dll;` to the *Test Assembly* option of the Run tests task.